# What is the "ponytail" in a knight's helmet called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

Does the ponytail thing in a knight's helmet have its own name? Or are they just called ponytails?

[image]

Comment: That is not human hair.  It is a feather, or fabric, item.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is a ***Plume*** -

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=plume)

> *late 14c.,* "a feather" (especially a large and conspicuous one), from Old French plume "soft feather, down; feather bed," and directly from Latin pluma "a feather, down; the first beard," from PIE root *pleus- "to pluck; a feather, fleece" (cf. Old English fleos "fleece"). Meaning "a long streamer of smoke, etc." is first attested 1878.

The Roman plumes were made from horse hair though. Feathers would not survive long.

Comment: When I think of _plumes_ nowadays, my mind immediately goes to [marching band uniforms](http://www.uwec.edu/alumni/PhotoAlbum/homecoming/12/images/Band-Halftime.gif), many of which use rather garish plumes.

Comment: But they are all over the top http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/91/Household_cavalry_Hyde_Park.jpg look like hair extenstions :)